# Error in program to get the max value

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to get the maximum value but it is not working. The calculation is performed inside a function named `max_number`.

What is the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int max_number(int storeX[], int i)
{
    int max=0,x;
    for(x=0;x<i;x++)
    {
        if(storeX[x]<max)
        {
            max = storeX[x];
        }
        return max;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,x,numbers,max;
    printf("how many numbers do you want to compare?\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    int storeX[i];
    for(x=0;x<i;x++)
    {
        printf("the %d number is:",x+1);
        scanf("%d",&numbers);
        numbers=storeX[x];
    }
    max=max_number(storeX,i);
    printf("the max number is: %d",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're telling `scanf` to store the number it captures into `numbers`, but then you just overwrite that with some uninitialized data from your `storeX` array.  Behaviour is exactly as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems in the code, have made changes to the code to make it work. Check the comments in the code to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int max_number(int storeX[], int i)
{
    int max=INT_MIN,x;   //In case you array has all negative numbers
    for(x=0;x<i;x++)
    {
        if(storeX[x]>max)  // This if condition is wrong
        {
            max = storeX[x];
        }
        //return max;        // You need to iterate the whole array
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int i,x,numbers,max;
    printf("how many numbers do you want to compare?\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    int storeX[i];
    for(x=0;x<i;x++)
    {
        printf("the %d number is:",x+1);
        scanf("%d",&storeX[x]);  // Need to pass a reference to the array index
        //numbers=storeX[x];    //dosen't assign the value to storeX[x] instead the otherway around
    }
    max=max_number(storeX,i);
    printf("the max number is: %d\n",max);
    return 0;
}
```